# NGINX Config for Express Static Files

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, nginx-location

I have nginx running and I also have an express backend server with a react front end. The issue I'm having is with the static files from express. For instance I have some handlebar view files with a header that calls to css/style.css and the js directory as well which currently works in Chrome but not in IE, Edge or Safari. In those browsers the console shows a 404 and the styling doesn't apply of course.

I call for the style.css from my handlebars view page like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

It should be setup so that if I were to visit http://sitename.com/css/style.css I would see the style.css from /var/www/sitename.com/html/node/public/css/style.css location. Which actually appears to work in Chrome but not in other browsers.

I have this statement in my express app

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I have a directory structure like so:

```
/var/www/sitename.com/html/node (node express app is running from here)
/var/www/sitename.com/html/node/public (public folder for static files from express)
                                   -> css (folder)
                                   -> js (folder)
```

my nginx is setup as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/sitename.com/html;
  index index.php index.html;
  server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;

  location /phpmyadmin {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location / {
    root /var/www/sitename.com/html/node/public/;
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:42134; 
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  }

  # set max upload size
  client_max_body_size 2G;
  fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/http_access.log combined;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/http_error.log;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  } 

  location ~ \.php$
  {
    try_files      $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd) {
    deny all;
  }

  # set long EXPIRES header on static assets
  location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
    expires 30d;
    access_log off;
  }
}
```

Comment: Strange because you serve the public files via nginx, so you should comment the `app.use(express.static('public'));` in your app.js. You should try to set the index directive inside the @backend server too (I think)...

Comment: Commenting out the express.static line in my app.js results in no change. I also tested adding the index directive under @backend, didn't seem to make any noticeable differences.

Answer (score 1):

The solution ended up being to remove the express.static line in the app.js and then in the nginx config I had to rearrange things as so:

```
    server {
    listen 80;
server_name _;

    root /var/www/sitename.com/html;
    index index.php index.html;

    server_name sitename.com www.sitename.com;

    location /phpmyadmin {
            root /var/www/sitename.com/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

location /dashboard {
            index index.php index.html;
            try_files $uri @backend;
            }

location /static {
            root /var/www/sitename.com/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }



    location / {
            index index.php index.html;
            try_files $uri @backend;
            }

    location @backend {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:42134; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # Following is necessary for Websocket support
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}


    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/http_access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/http_error.log;

    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }   

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        try_files      $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(htaccess|htpasswd) {
        deny all;
    }

    # set long EXPIRES header on static assets
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
    }

}
```